# py2neo: How to iterate over all relationships taking the start node and the end node?

Tags: graph, neo4j, py2neo

How to iterate over all relationships on a graph taking the start node and the end node?. I Tried:

```
import sys
import time
import json
from py2neo import Graph, Node, authenticate, Relationship
graph =Graph()
cypher = graph.cypher

def handle_row(row):
    a,b = row
    ... do some stuff with a,b

cypher.execute("match (a)-[]->(b) return a, b", row_handler=handle_row)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
`typeError: <function handle_row at ...> is not JSON serializable`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cypher.execute()` function does not take a result handler as argument. It takes query parameters either as a dictionary or as keyword arguments. These parameters are then sent to neo4j as JSON. Your `handle_row` function is not JSON serializable, hence the `TypeError`.

To do something with all your nodes try this:

```
result = graph.cypher.execute('MATCH (a)-[]->(b) RETURN a, b')
for row in result:
    print(row)
    print(row[0])
    print(row[2])
```

See examples here: http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#api-cypher

Comment: Just seen in the documentation that I also could used: `for r in graph.cypher.stream("MATCH (a)-[]->(b) RETURN id(a), id(b)"):
    print (r[0],r[1])`. Would you know the difference in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I'd say stream is better for large result sets.